# After Add the Record Alert Message is not displayed Servlet Ajax

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

After Add the Record  Record is insert into the database successfully but Alert Message is not displayed using Servlet Ajax. i am tring this since yesterday i didn't solve the problem yet.  what i tried so far i attached below. i don't know what was the problem is.i need to display alert message after add the record thats what i need.

**Form**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<form class="card" id="frmProject"> 
    <div class="bg-2form-group" align="left">
        <label class="form-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="fname" size="30px"  required>

    </div>
     <div class="bg-2form-group" align="left">
        <label class="form-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" name="lname" size="30px"  required>

    </div>


    <div class="card" align="right">

        <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-info" onclick="addProject()">Add
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="clear" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="reSet()">Reset</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
var isNew = true;
            function addProject()
            {
                if($("#frmProject").valid())
                {     
                    var url="";
                    var data= "";
                    var method;

                    if(isNew==true)
                    {
                        url = 'add';
                        data = $("#frmProject").serialize();
                        method = 'POST'
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        url = 'update';
                        data = $("#frmProject").serialize() + "&catid=" + catid;
                        method = 'POST'
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: method,
                        url : url,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data : data,

                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            if(isNew ==true)
                            {
                                alert("Record Adddeddd");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 alert("Record Updatee");  
                            }        
                        }   
                    }); 
                }
            }
```

**Servlet Page**

```
Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lname");


         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/details", "root", "");
         String query = "insert into record(firstname,lastname)values(?,?)";          
         pst = con.prepareStatement(query);        
         pst.setString(1, fname);
         pst.setString(2, lname);
         pst.executeUpdate();

         String greetings = "Record Addeddddd ";
         response.setContentType("text/plain");
         response.getWriter().write(greetings);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$.ajax({
                        type: method,
                        url : url,
                       **// dataType: 'JSON',**
                        data : data,
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            if(isNew ==true)
                            {
                                alert("Record Adddeddd");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 alert("Record Updatee");
                            }
                        }
                    });**

please try to remove // dataType: 'JSON' and run your code.

Comment: sir i have one doubt in servelt how to add,edit,delete pages create the same package any solution sir